# Normal subgroup of 2-transitive group

Tags: group-theory

I want to show that if $G$ acts faithfully and $2$-transitively on a set $X$, and $N$ is a non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$, then $N$ acts transitively on $X$.

I'm convinced that I have to use the fact that $G$ preserves the orbits of $N$'s action on $X$-- that is, for some orbit $Y$ on $N$'s action on $X$, and $g \in G$, $gY$ is also an orbit of $N$'s action on $X$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

(I am going to let $G$ act on $X$ from the right.) Choose $1 \ne n \in N$ and suppose $\alpha^n = \beta \ne \alpha$. Since $G$ is $2$-transitive, for any $\gamma \ne \alpha$, there exists $g \in G$ with $\alpha^g=\alpha$ and $\beta^g=\gamma$, and then $\alpha^{g^{-1}ng} = \gamma$.

This result generalizes to $G$ being primitive.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $G$ acts on$X$ by conjugation, though...

Comment: No I am not - what makes you think that? $\alpha^g$ is just my preferred notation for the image of $\alpha$ under $g$. Replace it by $g\alpha$ if you prefer.

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure I understand how $(g^{-1}ng)\alpha=\gamma$.

Comment: is it just that $n\alpha = \beta, g\alpha=\alpha, g\beta=\gamma; g^{-1}\in Stab(\alpha); \Rightarrow (gn)\alpha = \gamma \Rightarrow (gng^{-1})\alpha=\gamma$?

Comment: Obviously if you insist on using left action then you have to replace $g^{-1}ng$ by $gng^{-1}$.